# Update list with list contents coming from method in loop

Tags: java, string, list

I have a condition like this

```
    List<String> mainList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
      mainList = getList();
    }

private static List<String> getList() {
    List<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();
    listName.add("String");
    return listName;
  }
```

As `mainList` is getting `List<String>` in return and `mainList` itself a **list of Strings**. How can I keep updating `mainList` with those strings in `listName` **returning** from method.

If you give any solution will that also apply on `Maps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append a list to an existing list use the `addAll` method:

```
mainList.addAll(getList());
```

For `Map` you have `putAll`:

```
map1.putAll(map2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
      mainList.addAll(getList());
}
```

For maps, you can do it like this:

```
Map<String, String> mainMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
          mainMap.putAll(getMap());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> mainList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
  mainList.getAll(getList());
}

private static List<String> getList() {
  List<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();
  listName.add("String");
  return listName;
}
```

Map:

```
Map<String, String> mainMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
      mainMap.putAll(getMap());
}

 private static Map<String> getMap() {
   Map<String> mapName = new Map<String>();
   mapName .put("String");
   return mapName ;
 }
```